# How to I release within a release? e.g. On release of a kit assembly, I want to create/release a one step transfer

Tags: transactions, release, acumatica

Have an extension already, issue is the Transaction, I believe.

So, in particular circumstances, want to transfer the finished item
  Creation works, but the Release doesn't (in particular, "iNTransferEntry.release.Press();".
  Other code also has issues including most release logic within a transaction
  Transaction is outside of my control, since I'm extending the release, already within the release transaction.  I can accept something that just gets the "New" release out of the existing transaction, so can fail in that release if leave the unreleased document out there

Rough code, within PXGraphExtension, protected virtual void INRegister_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted del)

```
#region Transfer Back
INTransferEntry iNTransferEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INTransferEntry>();
INRegister iNRegister = new INRegister();
iNRegister.DocType = INDocType.Transfer;
iNRegister = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Insert(iNRegister);
iNRegister.TransferType = INTransferType.OneStep;
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "fa2a598d-6df0-4f66-9e95-01c751ae2765"));
// From always the current kit assembly site (e.g. Move from wherever it was made)
iNRegister.SiteID = kae.Document.Current.SiteID.GetValueOrDefault();
iNRegister = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Update(iNRegister);
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", "481f805f-4c1e-47b9-9624-814b722c2c4a", iNRegister.SiteID));
// To always the Work order site, so can use from there
iNRegister.ToSiteID = WorkOrderGraph.WOrderHeader.Current.SiteID.GetValueOrDefault();
iNRegister = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Update(iNRegister);
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", "4c2b9232-9149-4f8f-8b16-4be9e474ab2e", iNRegister.ToSiteID));
// Create the Item
INTran iNTran = (INTran)iNTransferEntry.transactions.Cache.CreateInstance();
// Always the finished good
iNTran.InventoryID = kae.Document.Current.InventoryID;
iNTran.SiteID = iNRegister.SiteID;
// Always the full quantity, and the existing UOM.  So All should move back.
iNTran.Qty = kae.Document.Current.Qty;
iNTran.UOM = kae.Document.Current.UOM;
iNTran.TranDesc = string.Format("{0} Completing {1}", WorkOrderGraph.WOrderHeader.Current.WONbr.TrimEnd(), kae.Document.Current.RefNbr.TrimEnd());
iNTran = iNTransferEntry.transactions.Update(iNTran);
#region Release hold, if needed
if (iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.Hold.GetValueOrDefault())
{
    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "651c1afd-f6de-43ad-8dae-9898b0ac9774"));
    iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.Hold = false;
    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "f50e42c8-08d8-4bf3-b122-f41f1c8e54c4"));
    iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Update(iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current);
    Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "352f80e4-b59e-42db-80a4-7a62525bdc09"));
}
#endregion
#region Fix the control totals, even though they may not be needed
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "7c2cb9dd-5905-4e49-8c3d-02b2adf73202"));
iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.ControlAmount = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.TotalAmount;
iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.ControlCost = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.TotalCost;
iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.ControlQty = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current.TotalQty;
iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current = iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Update(iNTransferEntry.CurrentDocument.Current);
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "ee61774a-0e8c-4ddf-86e0-0b9a0da13e64"));
#endregion
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "74e70f04-a807-4451-8168-ce57b8080475"));
iNTransferEntry.Actions.PressSave();
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "c0bca41c-3f6f-46a0-9c52-872162c090fe"));
iNTransferEntry.release.Press();
Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "133bce7a-c597-426a-91c0-2e397895300e"));
PXTrace.WriteInformation(Messages.Matrix_WorkOrder_Action_Released1Step, iNTransferEntry.transfer.Current.RefNbr);
```

Error raised, within the trace:
PX.Data.PXOperationCompletedSingleErrorException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

more detail on the error:

```
2018-08-10 13:29:59Z [35] Error w3wp.exe 0: 23803b8a-d4f4-4523-b310-a6ddd16bc3bd 000021 PX.Data.PXOperationCompletedSingleErrorException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> PX.Data.PXOperationCompletedSingleErrorException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> PX.Data.PXDatabaseException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand command)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.updateCommon(IDbCommand cmd, String tableName, Int32 cid, PXDataFieldParam[] pars, AuditTable audit, Boolean isVisibilityUpdate, Boolean sharedDelete, companySetting setting)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass127_0.<update>b__1(String tn, IDbCommand cmd)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.usingDbCommand[T](Func`3 fnUsefulActions, String commandText, String tableName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.usingDbCommand[T](Func`3 fnUsefulActions, String commandText, String tableName)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.Update(Type table, PXDataFieldParam[] pars)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabase.Update[Table](PXDataFieldParam[] pars)
   at PX.Objects.CS.AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumberInt(PXCache sender, Object data, String numberingID, Nullable`1 dateTime, String lastAssigned, String& LastNbr, String& WarnNbr, Nullable`1& NumberingSEQ) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\CS\Descriptor\Attribute.cs:line 2867
   at PX.Objects.CS.AutoNumberAttribute.GetNextNumber(PXCache sender, Object data, String numberingID, Nullable`1 dateTime, String lastAssigned, String& LastNbr, String& WarnNbr, Nullable`1& NumberingSEQ) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\CS\Descriptor\Attribute.cs:line 2954
   at PX.Objects.CS.AutoNumberAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\CS\Descriptor\Attribute.cs:line 2802
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
   at PX.Objects.GL.JournalEntry.Persist() in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\GL\JournalEntry.cs:line 1201
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.PressImpl(Boolean internalCall, Boolean externalCall)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.Press()
   at PX.Objects.IN.INReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 5083
   at PX.Objects.IN.INReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProcR(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 4472
   at PX.Objects.IN.INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(List`1 list, Boolean isMassProcess) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 119
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PX.Objects.IN.INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(List`1 list, Boolean isMassProcess) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 145
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Object key, Byte[] timeStamp, PXToggleAsyncDelegate method, Boolean forceAsync)
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.StartOperation(PXGraph graph, PXToggleAsyncDelegate method)
   at PX.Objects.IN.INTransferEntry.Release(PXAdapter adapter) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INTransferEntry.cs:line 130
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.PressImpl(Boolean internalCall, Boolean externalCall)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.Press()
   at MaxQ.Products.SupplyChain.MQSCINDocumentReleaseExt.INRegister_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted del) in C:\_Development\Acumatica Development\MaxQ Products\Supply Chain Planning\Source\Graph\MQSCINDocumentReleaseExt.cs:line 336
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisted(Object item, PXDBOperation operation, PXTranStatus tranStatus, Exception exception)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persisted(Boolean isAborted, Exception exception)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
   at PX.Objects.IN.INReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 5091
   at PX.Objects.IN.INReleaseProcess.ReleaseDocProcR(JournalEntry je, INRegister doc) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 4472
   at PX.Objects.IN.INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(List`1 list, Boolean isMassProcess) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 119
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PX.Objects.IN.INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(List`1 list, Boolean isMassProcess) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\INDocumentRelease.cs:line 145
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Object key, Byte[] timeStamp, PXToggleAsyncDelegate method, Boolean forceAsync)
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.StartOperation(PXGraph graph, PXToggleAsyncDelegate method)
   at PX.Objects.IN.KitAssemblyEntry.Release(PXAdapter adapter) in F:\Bld2\AC-FULL2017R2-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\IN\KitAssemblyEntry.cs:line 138
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.PressImpl(Boolean internalCall, Boolean externalCall)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.Press()
   at MaxQ.Products.SupplyChain.WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.KitAssemblyReleaseOrDelete(MQSCWorkOrd& workOrd) in C:\_Development\Acumatica Development\MaxQ Products\Supply Chain Planning\Source\Graph\WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.cs:line 1204
   at MaxQ.Products.SupplyChain.WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.ProcessWOrders(List`1 WOrdersToProcess, Nullable`1 Consolidate) in C:\_Development\Acumatica Development\MaxQ Products\Supply Chain Planning\Source\Graph\WorkOrderReportProductionProcess.cs:line 133
```

Comment: how long this operation took?

Comment: It's a little vague, but fails due to database locking.  Seems to time out after ~ 20 seconds.

Comment: Tried a New PXConnection, but that fails due to transaction locking as well.  I'm creating transfer within the first transaction, so nothing else can "See" it, until it's committed.  So if the release process does ANYTHING outside of the "Current" transaction scope, then it will fail.  e.g. find   "using (new PXConnectionScope())" within INDocumentRelease, these WILL prevent it from being callable from within another transaction.   This particular instance is "Acumatica 2017 R2 Build 17.200.0401"